# Visual Studio UML class diagram generated code bug

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

I've been trying to get generated code from my class diagram, but it doesn't compile because some of the generated classes look like this:

```
public class List : Block
{
    public virtual {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I think this happens because the code generation is trying to treat the inheritance relationship as a traversalable association. However I can't prove it or do anything about it because I'm not sure how to debug the code generation templates.

I've copied them from %ProgramFiles%\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\ARCHITECTURE TOOLS\EXTENSIBILITY\Templates\Text\ and they are being referenced if I right click on the UML Model Explorer root and Setup Code Generation.

To run them, I right-click and select Generate Code. To debug them I need to take the same action but somehow get Visual Studio into a debugging mode, whether automagically or via attach to process. Some online references indicate that I should see options to run t4 templates within Visual Studio but I can't find those.

The questions:

- How do I debug the t4 templates being run by UML code generation?
- Has anyone else experienced this issue. It makes the code generation from a UML diagram useless (it's hard to imagine a class diagram without some inheritance).

I am running VS2015 Enterprise.

Comment: I am not sure how you can debug the t4 templates directly from the UML Model explorer.  Unless you have unnamed attributes in your model, it could be a bug in the CSharpHelpers.t4 template.  The WritePropertyDefinition() function happily writes properties without a name.